# Switch between fraktur and standard fonts

Tags: yfonts

I am trying to create a document which I can typeset either using the standard font or fraktur.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}

\frakfamily

Test

Tes:t

This:: should have one colon.

Another example: The colon should stay here.

\end{document}
```

Typesetting it as-is, there is no problem. If I remove the `\frakfamily` command to typeset the document with the standard font, the colon used for customizing the fraktur output is displayed inside the output.

How to switch between fraktur and standard fonts on-the-fly? And is there a way to declare the usage of fraktures for all document content inside the preamble?

To clarify it a bit more: The document should be typeset either completely with fraktur or with the standard fonts. As I do not want to create two different source files, I was searching for a way to automatically suppress single colons after an `s` when using the standard fonts. (This would be easy when using an external script, but I would need another intermediate source file beside the existing one in this case.)

Comment: in the fractur font `s:` is a ligature. In pdflatex it is imho not possible to add such a ligature on the fly to a font. With xelatex or lualatex it could be possible.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I understand your comment correctly, one would have to define the `s:` ligature in the used standard font to behave the same like `s` to solve the problem? If it is not possible with `pdflatex`, I might be able to switch the engine - while I prefer `lualatex` over `xelatex`.

Comment: If you are willing to switch engines, maybe this answer will help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218326/87678

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With pdflatex you could try something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{yfonts}

\sfcode`\s=1001
\catcode`\:=\active
\DeclareRobustCommand:{\ifnum\spacefactor=1001 \spacefactor=1000 \else \string:\fi}

\begin{document}

%\frakfamily

Test

Tes:t

This:: should have one colon.

Another example: The colon should stay here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With lualatex you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature({
    name = "ligc",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ["s"] = { "s", ":" },
    }})}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[RawFeature=+ligc]    
\begin{document}

Test

Tes:t

This:: should have one colon.

Another example: The colon should stay here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the `lualatex` solution works fine, while the `pdflatex` solution seems to fail with an `Improper \spacefactor` error when used within section headers (`\section{Tes:t}` for example).

Comment: Make the : robust: `\DeclareRobustCommand:`

Answer (score 3):

With help from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218326/87678), here's a solution with `xelatex`:

Find on your system the file `tex-text.map` and copy it to your working directory under the name `fraktur.map` (or whatever you want). Then append to it a line so that it looks like:

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

; additions to suppress fraktur ligature
U+0073 U+003A   <>  U+0073  ; s: -> LATIN SMALL LETTER S
```

Then run

```
teckit_compile fraktur.map
```

which will create a file named fraktur.tec.

Then, you can use this mapping file with `xelatex` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Mapping=fraktur]

\begin{document}

Test

Tes:t

This:: should have one colon.

Another example: The colon should stay here.


\frakfamily

Test

Tes:t

This:: should have one colon.

Another example: The colon should stay here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to affect section titles, see `\section{Tes:t}` for example.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh you are using scrbook, which sets the section titles in sans serif, so you will have to add the mapping instruction also to the sans family with e.g. `\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}[Mapping=fraktur]`