# Adding new ligatures to an overleaf-document

Tags: fontspec, overleaf, ligatures

I'm currently transcribing some old books using overleaf as my compiler of choice. I wanted to copy some old ligatures (æ, œ, ct, ...).

I have already read some questions, (e.g. [How add my own ligature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218318/how-add-my-own-ligature)) where it's been said to use the fontspec-package (and XeTeX, of course) and include another mapping. Unlucky, this doesn't work out on overleaf (or I failed myself) and now I'm wondering, whether there is another way to do so.

```
\documentclass[11pt, doublespacing]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek, latin]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\input{preamble} %(nothing too important)

\usepackage{fontspec}[Mapping=ligaturae.map]

\begin{document}

...

\end{document}
```

I actually copied the map-file from the guide above ([How add my own ligature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218318/how-add-my-own-ligature)) and added changed two lines to the custom ligatures I wanted

```
; additions by me
U+0061 U+0065   <>  U+00E6  ; ae -> æ
U+006F U+0065   <>  U+0153  ; oe -> œ
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you provide more details (regarding what font used, etc.) with a `MWE`?

Comment: I added some details. regarding fonts: I prefer the 'classic' LaTeX-font, TNR, I suppose, but if there are better/easier ones, I'll change.

Comment: For many fonts, this is `Ligatures=Rare` or `Ligatures=Historic`.

Comment: Latin Modern doesn’t have the `ct`; you need to find a font that has what you want, then ask how to use it, because the method will depend on how the font’s features were defined.

Comment: @Davislor I tried, but the fonts, I'm using right now, don't support those. Do you have any in mind, which might work?

Comment: @Thérèse ct isn't important to me, but æ and œ are.

Comment: I don’t know of a language in which *all* occurrences of `ae` and `oe` become `æ` and `œ` (even in French, spelling a word with `œ` is sometimes incorrect); in my opinion, it would be easier to type `æ` and `œ` directly where appropriate than to create a font feature and turn it on or off as needed. This is possible because — unlike some ligatures — `æ` and `œ` are in Unicode.